# How can i obtain the value of the selector at each change by the user

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, parameter-passing

I would like to know how to get the value of the selector each time the user will click on a value.

The goal of this is to pass the variable to php and to affect an other one in javascript.

I see the  [documentation here](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/demo_interactions.html#a_change) speaking about `OnChange` but I do not understand it at all.

```js
var custom_values = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500];
var my_from = custom_values.indexOf(100);
var my_to = custom_values.indexOf(500);

$(".js-range-slider").ionRangeSlider({
  grid: true,
  from: my_from,
  to: my_to,
  values: custom_values,
  min: 0,
  postfix: "BRO",
  onChange: function(data) {
    console.dir(data);
  }
});
```

```html
<!--Plugin CSS file with desired skin-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.3.0/css/ion.rangeSlider.min.css" />

<!--jQuery-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--Plugin JavaScript file-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.3.0/js/ion.rangeSlider.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="js-range-slider" name="my_range" value="" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".js-range-slider").on("change", function () {
    var $inp = $(this);
    var from = $inp.prop("value"); // reading input value
    var from2 = $inp.data("from"); // reading input data-from attribute

    console.log(from, from2); // FROM value
});
```

Comment: Oh shit, that was working since a long time, it was in the console , i'm tired..  Thanks to have confirm the same code as i see :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the change event handler to the slider as follows.

```
$(".js-range-slider").on("change", function () {
    // Do whatever you want here
});
```

for additional information see Jquery docs 
https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: Thanks too :) ( there is no button to confirm for the first answer..)

Comment: You can check under the down vote button to accept the answer